# reveal.js HTML not evaluated

Tags: html, codeigniter, html-parsing, reveal.js

I am using Hakim El Hattab's amazing reveal.js, and besides the problem below (which is due to my placeholders I noticed...), the script is working awesome for me.

Due to this being because of my placeholders, the problem is not with the script, but I believe that there will be some genius here somewhere that could point me in the right direction with this.

I am using the following HTML in my CMS:

```
<div class="societe-tpl-1">
    <div class="societe-tpl-1-header">
        [[HOME]]
        <div class="societe-tpl-1-header-separator">|</div>
        [[CONTENTS]]
        [[INDEX]]
        [[DOWN]]
        [[UP]]
        [[NEXT]]
        [[PREVIOUS]]
    </div>
    <div class="societe-tpl-1-content">
        <div class="societe-tpl-4-contents retro-apps">
            <div class="third">
                <div class="pg-number">[[PAGENUM]]</div>
                <h1>[[HEAD1]]</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="third">
                [[IMAGE1]]
                [[IMAGE2]]
                [[IMAGE3]]
            </div>
            <div class="third">
                <article>
                    <h2>[[SUBHEAD_1]]</h2>
                    <p>[[SUBTEXT_1]]</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>[[SUBHEAD_2]]</h2>
                    <p>[[SUBTEXT_2]]</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>[[SUBHEAD_3]]</h2>
                    <p>[[SUBTEXT_3]]</p>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="societe-tpl-1-footer">
        <div class="societe-tpl-1-footer-nextmonth">
            <a href="#">next month</a>
        </div>    
        <div class="societe-tpl-1-footer-mainsite">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.renault.co.za">www.renault.co.za</a>
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Using my CMS based on Code Igniter, I replace the placeholders with the appropriate code which I read from MySQL database. Where I have the the placeholders, the HTML does not get evaluated, but the HTML in the "Next month" link does get evaluated.

[image: Example output problem]

Anyone with any idea why my code in placeholders does not get evaluated? I am using a PHP script that replace the placeholders with their real content before page rendering (Code Igniter's display_override hook), so they are replaced before reveal.js kicks in, as far as I can tell.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The data got saved in the database as HTML entities (`&lt;` and `&gt;`) and therefore the filter replacing the `<a>` tags did not work.